# format date (received in milliseconds) in yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I am getting date in milliseconds and I converted it into IST by :

```
new Date(1487651547000)
```

which outputs

Tue Feb 21 2017 10:02:27 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Now, I need this date in below format :

2017-02-21 10:02:27

I looked for links here on stackoverflow, but none was able to be suitable for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the [methods of the `Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), which allow you to extract whichever parts of the date you like? (You can then concatentate them together in whatever order you like.) jQuery isn't going to help with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short and Sweetttt....

```js
var myDate = new Date(1559736267189);
alert(myDate.getFullYear() + '-' +('0' + (myDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+ '-' +  ('0' + myDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + ' '+myDate.getHours()+ ':'+('0' + (myDate.getMinutes())).slice(-2)+ ':'+myDate.getSeconds());
```

Comment: Thanks Punit, appreciate this code!

Comment: this did not work.  it returns the date plus hh:mm:ss but no milliseconds

Comment: @spacedog, you an simply use getMilliseconds() , Also would like to inform you that I gave the answer as per the op's requirement

Answer (score 1):

Use below function in fiddle

```
     <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/pareshmutha1900/mbcmf0k4/">Link</a>

     var dateFormat = function () {
            var    token = /d{1,4}|m{1,4}|yy(?:yy)?|([HhMsTt])\1?|[LloSZ]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'/g,
                timezone = /\b(?:[PMCEA][SDP]T|(?:Pacific|Mountain|Central|Eastern|Atlantic) (?:Standard|Daylight|Prevailing) Time|(?:GMT|UTC)(?:[-+]\d{4})?)\b/g,
                timezoneClip = /[^-+\dA-Z]/g,
                pad = function (val, len) {
                    val = String(val);
                    len = len || 2;
                    while (val.length < len) val = "0" + val;
                    return val;
                };

            // Regexes and supporting functions are cached through closure
            return function (date, mask, utc) {
                var dF = dateFormat;

                // You can't provide utc if you skip other args (use the "UTC:" mask prefix)
                if (arguments.length == 1 && Object.prototype.toString.call(date) == "[object String]" && !/\d/.test(date)) {
                    mask = date;
                    date = undefined;
                }

                // Passing date through Date applies Date.parse, if necessary
                date = date ? new Date(date) : new Date;
                if (isNaN(date)) throw SyntaxError("invalid date");

                mask = String(dF.masks[mask] || mask || dF.masks["default"]);

                // Allow setting the utc argument via the mask
                if (mask.slice(0, 4) == "UTC:") {
                    mask = mask.slice(4);
                    utc = true;
                }

                var    _ = utc ? "getUTC" : "get",
                    d = date[_ + "Date"](),
                    D = date[_ + "Day"](),
                    m = date[_ + "Month"](),
                    y = date[_ + "FullYear"](),
                    H = date[_ + "Hours"](),
                    M = date[_ + "Minutes"](),
                    s = date[_ + "Seconds"](),
                    L = date[_ + "Milliseconds"](),
                    o = utc ? 0 : date.getTimezoneOffset(),
                    flags = {
                        d:    d,
                        dd:   pad(d),
                        ddd:  dF.i18n.dayNames[D],
                        dddd: dF.i18n.dayNames[D + 7],
                        m:    m + 1,
                        mm:   pad(m + 1),
                        mmm:  dF.i18n.monthNames[m],
                        mmmm: dF.i18n.monthNames[m + 12],
                        yy:   String(y).slice(2),
                        yyyy: y,
                        h:    H % 12 || 12,
                        hh:   pad(H % 12 || 12),
                        H:    H,
                        HH:   pad(H),
                        M:    M,
                        MM:   pad(M),
                        s:    s,
                        ss:   pad(s),
                        l:    pad(L, 3),
                        L:    pad(L > 99 ? Math.round(L / 10) : L),
                        t:    H < 12 ? "a"  : "p",
                        tt:   H < 12 ? "am" : "pm",
                        T:    H < 12 ? "A"  : "P",
                        TT:   H < 12 ? "AM" : "PM",
                        Z:    utc ? "UTC" : (String(date).match(timezone) || [""]).pop().replace(timezoneClip, ""),
                        o:    (o > 0 ? "-" : "+") + pad(Math.floor(Math.abs(o) / 60) * 100 + Math.abs(o) % 60, 4),
                        S:    ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"][d % 10 > 3 ? 0 : (d % 100 - d % 10 != 10) * d % 10]
                    };

                return mask.replace(token, function ($0) {
                    return $0 in flags ? flags[$0] : $0.slice(1, $0.length - 1);
                });
            };
        }();

        // Some common format strings
        dateFormat.masks = {
            "default":      "ddd mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:ss",
            shortDate:      "m/d/yy",
            mediumDate:     "mmm d, yyyy",
            longDate:       "mmmm d, yyyy",
            fullDate:       "dddd, mmmm d, yyyy",
            shortTime:      "h:MM TT",
            mediumTime:     "h:MM:ss TT",
            longTime:       "h:MM:ss TT Z",
            isoDate:        "yyyy-mm-dd",
            isoTime:        "HH:MM:ss",
            isoDateTime:    "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss",
            isoUtcDateTime: "UTC:yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss'Z'"
        };

        // Internationalization strings
        dateFormat.i18n = {
            dayNames: [
                "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat",
                "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
            ],
            monthNames: [
                "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec",
                "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
            ]
        };

        // For convenience...
        Date.prototype.format = function (mask, utc) {
            return dateFormat(this, mask, utc);
        };





    today = new Date();
    var dateString = today.format("yyyy-mm-dd h:mm");
    alert(dateString);
```

Comment: Yeah, that won't confuse the OP...

Answer (score -1):

You have to do it manually using getDate(), getMonth(), getYear() ,etc. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Or use library like Moment.js: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: I definitely recommend using Moment.js as well. In this case I think the correct formula would be `moment(1487651547000).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')`

Comment: This should be a comment, it's not an answer.